# how to start a java application system-independent at Windows startup

Tags: java, windows, registry

I want to automatically run a Java application under Windows at startup time, but not depending on a specical Windows or a special JRE-version.

Generally, a good way to run programs at Windows login time would be to add a registry entry under

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

But it seems as if the system PATH is not evaluated when Windows tries to run the programs listed in the registry's RUN section.

So these both entries do work:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin\javaw" -jar c:\path\to\java.jar
"C:\ProgramData\Oracle\java\javapath\javaw" -jar c:\path\to\java.jar
```

But this one doesn't come up:

```
javaw -jar c:\path\to\java.jar
```

Now, the latter works when manually entered in a console window because there the required PATH exists and is evaluated:

```
PATH=....;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;....
```

Now, I want to have the registry entry added from an automated installer programm and I would like to have it formed "windows-system-independent" (from Vista up to Win 10, and furthermore not depending from the version of the installed JRE). So I do not know a general path to the JRE and therefore I cannot add a specific RUN-command to the registry.

Does anyone know how to add JRE-calls system-independent correctly to the registry's RUN-section?

I've already tried with a command-file, e.g. "startup.cmd" with content `java -jar file.jar` there, have added a call of this file to the registry, and yes that worked, java was found, the application was started, but when using this method I have an annoying black command terminal window staying open all the time while the java app is running.

Thanx,
Tombo

Comment: For clarification: are you saying "the PATH is resolved if I call the batch file but it is not resolved if I call the javaw.exe through my registry run command" in your last sentence?

Comment: yes. obviously no PATH information available when a prg directly from the registry is called, but when called via the detour of a batch or cmd-file, the PATH does exists locally within the batch or cmd-file.

Answer (score 1):

Change your startup.cmd, from

```
java -jar file.jar
```

to

```
start java -jar file.jar
```

This will launch the java.exe in a new process an let your batch executor terminate.

Comment: that works, the black command terminal window is then at least not staying up permanently, but still flashing up shortly while it is executing the `start` which may still confuse the user. So I would prefer a way with no terminal window to be seen at all.

Comment: Have you tried the `/b` parameter such as `start /b java -jar file.jar` or maybe using  `/min` instead?